# Parallelizing loading data from MongoDB into python

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, parallel-processing, dask

All documents in my collection in MongoDB have the same fields. My goal is to load them into Python into `pandas.DataFrame` or `dask.DataFrame`.

I'd like to speedup the loading procedure by parallelizing it. My plan is to spawn several processes or threads. Each process would load a chunk of a collection, then these chunks would be merged together.

How do I do it correctly with MongoDB?

I have tried similar approach with PostgreSQL. My initial idea was to use `SKIP` and `LIMIT` in SQL queries. It has failed, since each cursor, opened for each particular query, started reading data table from the beginning and just skipped specified amount of rows. So I had to create additional column, containing record numbers, and specify ranges of these numbers in queries.

On the contrary, MongoDB assigns unique ObjectID to each document. However, I've found that it is impossible to subtract one ObjectID from another, they can be only compared with ordering operations: less, greater and equal.

Also, `pymongo` returns the cursor object, that supports indexing operation and has some methods, seeming useful for my task, like `count`, `limit`.

MongoDB connector for Spark accomplishes this task somehow. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Scala, therefore, it's hard for me to find out how they do it.

So, what is the correct way for parallel loading data from Mongo into python?

up to now, I've come to the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed

# import other modules.

collection = get_mongo_collection()
cursor = collection.find({ })

def process_document(in_doc):
    out_doc = # process doc keys and values
    return pd.DataFrame(out_doc)

df = dd.from_delayed( (delayed(process_document)(d) for d in cursor) )
```

However, it looks like `dask.dataframe.from_delayed` internally creates a list from passed generator, effectively loading all collection in a single thread.

*Update*. I've found [in docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/), that `skip` method of `pymongo.Cursor` starts from beginning of a collection too, as PostgreSQL. The same page suggests using pagination logic in the application. Solutions, that I've found so far, use sorted `_id` for this. However, they also store last seen `_id`, that implies that they also work in a single thread.

*Update2*. I've found the code of the partitioner in the official MongoDb Spark connector: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/7c76ed1821f70ef2259f8822d812b9c53b6f2b98/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/rdd/partitioner/MongoPaginationPartitioner.scala#L32

Looks like, initially this partitioner reads the key field from all documents in the collection and calculates ranges of values.

*Update3*: My incomplete solution.

Doesn't work, gets the exception from pymongo, because dask seems to incorrectly treat the `Collection` object:

```
/home/user/.conda/envs/MBA/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/delayed.pyc in <genexpr>(***failed resolving arguments***)
     81         return expr, {}
     82     if isinstance(expr, (Iterator, list, tuple, set)):
---> 83         args, dasks = unzip((to_task_dask(e) for e in expr), 2)
     84         args = list(args)
     85         dsk = sharedict.merge(*dasks)

/home/user/.conda/envs/MBA/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.pyc in __next__(self)
   2342 
   2343     def __next__(self):
-> 2344         raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not iterable")
   2345 
   2346     next = __next__

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not iterable
```

What raises the exception:

```
def process_document(in_doc, other_arg):
    # custom processing of incoming records
    return out_doc

def compute_id_ranges(collection, query, partition_size=50):
    cur = collection.find(query, {'_id': 1}).sort('_id', pymongo.ASCENDING)
    id_ranges = [cur[0]['_id']]
    count = 1
    for r in cur: 
        count += 1
        if count > partition_size:
            id_ranges.append(r['_id'])
            count = 0
    id_ranges.append(r['_id'])
    return zip(id_ranges[:len(id_ranges)-1], id_ranges[1: ])    


def load_chunk(id_pair, collection, query={}, projection=None):
    q = query
    q.update( {"_id": {"$gte": id_pair[0], "$lt": id_pair[1]}} )
    cur = collection.find(q, projection)

    return pd.DataFrame([process_document(d, other_arg) for d in cur])


def parallel_load(*args, **kwargs):
    collection = kwargs['collection']
    query = kwargs.get('query', {})
    projection = kwargs.get('projection', None)

    id_ranges = compute_id_ranges(collection, query)

    dfs = [ delayed(load_chunk)(ir, collection, query, projection) for ir in id_ranges ]
    df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
    return df

collection = connect_to_mongo_and_return_collection_object(credentials)

# df = parallel_load(collection=collection)

id_ranges = compute_id_ranges(collection)
dedf = delayed(load_chunk)(id_ranges[0], collection)
```

`load_chunk` perfectly runs when called directly. However, call `delayed(load_chunk)( blah-blah-blah )` fails with exception, mentioned above.

Comment: I think your intuition is right here that you want to construct several mongo queries that get different segments of the dataset and then use dask.delayed to load these in parallel, finally constructing some dask collection like a dataframe with `dask.dataframe.from_delayed`.  I think that the missing piece here is pagination.  I'll ping one of the Mongo devs for more information.

Comment: I've written a function loading chunk of documents with `_id`s between two predefined `_id`s. `def load_chunk(id_pair, collection, query={}, projection=None)`
 
But if I wrap this function in `delayed`, it tries to iterate Mongo collection, and gets the Exception that collection is not iterable.

`dfs = delayed(load_chunk)(id_pair, collection, query, projection)`

Sorry, don't have time for reproducible example right now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was looking into pymongo parallelization and this is what worked for me. It took my humble gaming laptop nearly 100 minutes to process my mongodb of 40 million documents. The CPU was 100% utilised I had to turn on the AC :)

I used skip and limit functions to split the database, then assigned batches to processes. The code is written for Python 3:

```
import multiprocessing
from pymongo import MongoClient

def your_function(something):
    <...>
    return result

def process_cursor(skip_n,limit_n):
    print('Starting process',skip_n//limit_n,'...')
    collection = MongoClient().<db_name>.<collection_name>
    cursor = collection.find({}).skip(skip_n).limit(limit_n)
    for doc in cursor:        
        <do your magic> 
        # for example:
        result = your_function(doc['your_field'] # do some processing on each document
        # update that document by adding the result into a new field
        collection.update_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, {'$set': {'<new_field_eg>': result} })

    print('Completed process',skip_n//limit_n,'...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_cores = 7                # number of splits (logical cores of the CPU-1)
    collection_size = 40126904 # your collection size
    batch_size = round(collection_size/n_cores+0.5)
    skips = range(0, n_cores*batch_size, batch_size)

    processes = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=process_cursor, args=(skip_n,batch_size)) for skip_n in skips]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

The last split will have a larger limit than the remaining documents, but that won't raise an error

Comment: It is a highly inefficient solution. Each cursor was starting from the start of collection, just discarding some records. It is said in Mongo manual.

Comment: @wl2776 True, I was aware of this point mentioned in the manuals. However, skipping is only done **once** when the processes start, and the worst case (i.e. last batch) took about 15 seconds to skip 35 million records. Once skipped, the cursor(s) continues from that point. Compared to the total processing time (100 minutes), skipping time is negligible for a 40 mil collection. In terms of performance, with my 30 lines of regex commands on each record, it processed an average of 400'000 documents per minute, or 6600 document per second

Comment: After a year I've come to conclusion that this is a good solution for scientific applications, where one needs to load data into RAM only once.

Comment: Excellent option for tweet NLP processing as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think `dask-mongo` will do the work for here. You can install it with pip or conda, and in the repo you can find some examples in a [notebook](https://github.com/coiled/dask-mongo/blob/main/examples/demo.ipynb).

`dask-mongo` will read the data you have in MongoDB as a Dask bag but then you can go from a Dask bag to a Dask Dataframe with `df = b.to_dataframe()` where `b` is the bag you read from mongo using with `dask_mongo.read_mongo`

Answer (score 0):

"Read the mans, thery're rulez" :)

`pymongo.Collection` has method [`parallel_scan`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.parallel_scan) that returns a list of cursors.

*UPDATE*. This function can do the job, if the collection does not change too often, and queries are always the same (my case). One could just store query results in different collections and run parallel scans.

Comment: Not yet. Some limitations still exist. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/8qshghoR4WU/9d3Chf7fFAAJ - the same ideas